# Why is my .htaccess file working on localhost but not on the server?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting, localhost

The .htaccess file I uploaded to the webserver, which was running fine on localhost (wamp server), isn't working as I wish it would.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^IMPRESSUM  about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^HOME  welcome.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^LOGIN  login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^LOGOUT  logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^SIGNUP  register.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?param1=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /account.php?param2=$1 [NC,L]
```

**The purpose of the code should be that the php files can be accessed without entering the file extension ("/home" instead of "/home.php"). But if the user enters something thats not a filename like "/something" it should be the same as "/index?param1=something".**

After it didn't work I tried many solutions I found on the internet. For example I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^IMPRESSUM  about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^HOME  welcome.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^LOGIN  login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^LOGOUT  logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^SIGNUP  register.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?param1=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /account.php?param2=$1 [NC,L]
```

I hope that someone knows a solution to my problem.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?param1=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /account.php?param2=$1 [NC,L]
```

The code first looks if a php file which's name is equal to the value behind slash exists. If it exists it will open the file, if such a file doesn't exist it will forward /something to /index.php?param1=something.